# Required Tag is not Found In Fix Protocol

Tags: fix-protocol, quickfixn

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bd203.png)

I'm working on Fix 4.4 protocol using quickfix library. My message is rejecting due to some tags and time accuracy problems.

```
ClientInitiator app = new ClientInitiator();
SessionSettings settings = new SessionSettings(@"D:\FixInitiator\FixInitiator\initiator.cfg");
QuickFix.Application application = new ClientInitiator();
FileStoreFactory storeFactory = new FileStoreFactory(settings);
ScreenLogFactory logFactory = new ScreenLogFactory(settings);
MessageFactory messageFactory = new DefaultMessageFactory();

SocketInitiator initiator = new SocketInitiator(application, storeFactory, settings, logFactory, messageFactory);
initiator.start();
Thread.Sleep(3000);
System.Collections.ArrayList list = initiator.getSessions();

SessionID sessionID = (SessionID)list[0];

//QuickFix44.NewOrderSingle order = new QuickFix44.NewOrderSingle();
//order.set(new OrderQty(45));
//order.set(new Price(25.4d));
//Console.WriteLine("Sending Order to Server");
//Session.sendToTarget(order, sessionID);

Console.ReadLine();

initiator.stop();
```

---

```
public class ClientInitiator : QuickFix.Application
{
    public void onCreate(QuickFix.SessionID value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Message OnCreate" + value.toString());
    }

    public void onLogon(QuickFix.SessionID value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("OnLogon" + value.toString());
    }

    public void onLogout(QuickFix.SessionID value)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Log out Session" + value.toString());
    }

    public void toAdmin(QuickFix.Message value, QuickFix.SessionID session)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called Admin :" + value.ToString());
    }

    public void toApp(QuickFix.Message value, QuickFix.SessionID session)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Called toApp :" + value.ToString());
    }

    public void fromAdmin(QuickFix.Message value, SessionID session)
    {
         Console.WriteLine("Got message from Admin" + value.ToString());
    }

    public void fromApp(QuickFix.Message value, SessionID session)
    {
        if (value is QuickFix44.ExecutionReport)
        {
            QuickFix44.ExecutionReport er = (QuickFix44.ExecutionReport)value;
            ExecType et = (ExecType)er.getExecType();

            if (et.getValue() == ExecType.FILL)
            {
                //TODO: implement code
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Got Execution Report from Server \n" + value.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Time accuracy means that your clock diverts too much from the clock of the counterparty. Best is to synchronize clock with e.g. NTP.

Comment: Also some log output of the exact error would probably be helpful.